# calculate hours per day with max value output over 1 week

Tags: sql, sql-server

Have a table

> Table: **schedule**
>   appointment
>   date
>   employee
>   duration

Looking to calculate the total duration of appointments for a specific date range, however I want to set a max value on the daily duration. So if someone booked 6 one-hour appointments but then put up another appointment for 12 hours, making that day a total of 18 hours, i want to set the max sum of duration per day to 10 hours for weekly calculations, how can i properly do that.? Using Sql Servman Management Studio

My code is below for the daily just not sure how to make it a total per employee:

```
select e.emp_id,Case when isnull(SUM(S.DURATION),0) > 10 then 10 else isnull(SUM(S.DURATION),0) end AS hours
from employee e left join Schedule s on s.emp_id = e.EMP_ID AND s.type <> 'z'
AND S.[DATE] >= CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),GETDATE()+1,121)
AND S.[DATE] <= CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),GETDATE()+5,121)
where e.INACTIVE = 'n'
AND E.U_ADVERTIS <> ''
group by s.[date],e.EMP_ID
order by e.EMP_ID
```

Answer (score 1):

How about DATEPART WK

Can also use DATEPART ISOWK

(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datepart-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

```
select 
    e.emp_id,
    DATEPART(WK,[S.Date]) as WeekNum,
    Case 
        when isnull(SUM(S.DURATION),0) > 10 then 10 
        else isnull(SUM(S.DURATION),0) 
    end AS hours
from employee e 
    left join Schedule s 
        on s.emp_id = e.EMP_ID 
            AND s.type <> 'z'
            AND S.[Date] > DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy, 0, GETDATE()) + 1, -1) -- Since the firs of the year, you can change this range up how you want/need
            --AND S.[DATE] >= CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),GETDATE()+1,121)
            --AND S.[DATE] <= CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),GETDATE()+5,121)
where e.INACTIVE = 'n'
    AND E.U_ADVERTIS <> ''
group by DATEPART(wk,[S.Date]),e.EMP_ID
order by e.EMP_ID,DATEPART(wk,s.date) desc
```